# Upload new photo to picasa by http request actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, http, actionscript, request, picasa

I want to add new photo to picasa server using picasa API in as3.
Can you tell me the form of http request and how to create binary image data to put in request.

API directory v2.0: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm well I've never tried this, but a couple of things to take note of if you do start attempting to implement this yourself.  First the link you dropped points to out-dated documentation be sure to use the new version: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=vi-VN#PostPhotos The next thing is you may need tighter control of the message body and headers than is available on the built in classes, this lib exposes some of that http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/ Lastly: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference?hl=vi-VN#Flash

Answer (score 1):

You can get the binary data for a image like this.

```
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myImage.width, myImage.height, true,0xFFFFFFFF);
    bd.draw(myImage);
```

Now you have the bitmap data of 'myImage' in var 'bd'.